# When to tell my employer about me working somewhere after end of contract

Tags: professionalism

I have freelancing like agreement that says that I work on project for 3 months. I am start working somewhere else just after this project. My boss wants to hire me after this project. When and How do I tell my current employer about that?

I would like to tell my boss because it affects project planning. I want to finish project( I am during my first year of working and only I work on it)

**Edited** following @bharal suggestions

Comment: I would say this is an entirely different question after the edit. Is this the one you want answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already taken a decision that you, yourself, view as somewhat rash: accepting another offer before giving the current employer a chance to try to hire you full-time. So now you are in the mode of damage control. So, ask yourself, *why* did you accept the other offer without first giving your current manager a chance to make a counteroffer? Then sit down with your current manager and tell her or him the simple truth. Honest is the best you are going to do here.

What you did was only 'rash' if there was a reasonable likelihood that your current boss would offer you a better compensation package than the new job. If it was already perfectly clear that the current situation could never come up with such a package, you haven't done anything precipitous at all.

Comment: New jobs gives me 40% raise + social benefits(health care and insurance)

Comment: So, you explain that to your current boss. Pretty likely, he offers congratulations on your good fortune. Much less likely, he says, 'I could have beat that.' Even less likely, he's grumpy.

Answer (score 10):

The answers here seem to have some kind of notion that leaving after a fixed term contract is a bad thing. It's not a bad thing. That's how contracting works. If they had wanted you to put roots down they would have hired you as a permanent staff member in the first place.

That you accepted another offer instead of taking an extension or becoming a permanent staff member is really your own business and there isn't enough info in the question to judge.

If your boss hired contractors he should appreciate these facts as well. Just be honest. Explain how valuable your time there has been, but that you won't be extending because you've already secured an exciting new opportunity. Just examine your contract and don't give over-early notice in a way that may risk early termination.

Answer (score 3):

Any reasonable company knows that you don't want to be out of work for long time, that's common sense. So it is also common sense that two or three months before your contract ends, you will be looking for another job unless you get a firm offer from the company you are working for right now.

If they *need* you or they *want* you urgently, then they should have told you at least two or three months before the job ends. If they ask you in the last week, then the expected answer would be "sorry, but I signed up for a different job ages ago". The most they could reasonably expect is that you have a gap between jobs and would be willing and able to work an extra week or two for them.

So there is no need to tell them anything about the new job. If they don't ask, they are either not interested (which is Ok; your old job is finished after all), or they are stupid. If they are stupid then there is a small chance that they expected you to continue working for them, and see you having a new job as quitting, and fire you. So informing your employer is at best pointless, and at worst damaging for you.

Answer (score 1):

`I have freelancing like agreement [...] it's up to them to prolong it.`

It seems that this is your answer right here. If the project takes longer than 3 months, you should let them know that you'll be unavailable, so that they can find someone else to take over.

If the project takes longer, you should also go over any paperwork you signed in case there's an "overdue" clause, or something to that effect.

Comment: There is no overdue clause, agreement says that I am going to work on project according to documentation in a given period,

Comment: @AdamKortez Then it's a matter of courtesy. Let them know as soon as possible. If, on the other hand, you want to continue working for them, I think I saw one or two questions on this site about going back on accepting an offer...